# How to create a NodeJs server accesible from an external connection without port forwarding

Tags: node.js, http, post, get

I'm currently working on a project where I use a raspberry pi as a server for a home automation server. It works fine on my local network but if I want to use it from an external computer I need to forward the used port on my router.

I'm trying to find a way to make http(s) gets to the server without having to forward the port on the router. I want this because if I would install the system at someone's place (a customer maybe in the future) I don't want to have to access their router.

I've tried using SSL and https but I ran into the same problem.

Is there any way this is possible or is it a lost case?

PS I can't use port 80 since it is already in use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://ngrok.com/ might be of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to get to the result you want:

1. Port forwarding, which you've dismissed
2. Giving the raspberry pi it's own public IP address (which requires a public IP address and access to the router to configure the traffic routing, which you've dismissed).

So let's go back to port forwards.

Most consumer routers these days support [NAT traversal via uPNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal).

You can use the [nat-pmp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nat-pmp) module to reqest the the router forward a port for you, without having to have direct access to the router.

Comment: Awesome! :) gonna look into it as soon as possible